# NodeJS get object from anonymous function based in custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, module

i try for the first time NodeJS and this server is just awesome, but i got a small problem and i dont understand what i'm doing wrong :(

I have two files : server.js and rules.js

rules.js read rules.html an must be return his content into object like that :

```
{'title':'Title','msg':'<div id="test">[...]</div>'}
```

**Rules.js**

```
exports.getRule = function(data) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var rulesPath = __dirname + '/views/rules.html';
    fs.readFile(rulesPath, {encoding:'utf-8'}, function(error, data) {
        if(!error){
            var rules = {"title":"Règles du chat","msg":data};
        } else {
            var rules = {"title":"Erreur lors de la récupèration des règles du chat","msg":"<div id=\"error\">Une ereur s'est produite lors de la récupération des données, veuillez rééssayer plus tard...<br />Si le problème persiste signalez le</div>"};
        }
        return rules;
    });
}
```

**Server.js**

```
// Load custom Rules module
var rules = require(__dirname + '/private/rules/rules.js');

// Perform actions when the client want open jQueryUI modal dialog 
socket.on('openBox', function(data) {
    if(data.id == 'rules'){
        console.log(rules.getRule(data));
        socket.emit('openBox',rules.getRule(data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function(error, data) {
    if (!error) {
        var rules = {
            "title": "Règles du chat",
            "msg": data
        };
    } else {
        var rules = {
            "title": "Erreur lors de la récupèration des règles du chat",
            "msg": "<div id=\"error\">Une ereur s'est produite lors de la récupération des données, veuillez rééssayer plus tard...<br />Si le problème persiste signalez le</div>"
        };
    }
    return rules;
}
```

This piece code is called call back function. This will be invoked by `fs.readFile` when the read data is available. When you `return` from the call back function, you are actually returning to `fs.readFile`, which most likely to ignore the return value of the call back. That is why your code is not working. What you should be doing is, to pass the call back function from `Server.js`, like this

```
socket.on('openBox', function(data) {
    if (data.id == 'rules') {
        rules.getRule(data, function(error, data) {
            if (!error) {
                var rulesObj = {
                    "title": "Règles du chat",
                    "msg": data
                };
            } else {
                var rulesObj = {
                    "title": "Erreur lors de la récupèration des règles du chat",
                    "msg": "<div id=\"error\">Une ereur s'est produite lors de la récupération des données, veuillez rééssayer plus tard...<br />Si le problème persiste signalez le</div>"
                };
            }
            console.log(rulesObj);
            socket.emit('openBox', rulesObj);
        });
    }
});
```

And change the `Rules.js` like this

```
exports.getRule = function(data, callBackFunction) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var rulesPath = __dirname + '/views/rules.html';
    fs.readFile(rulesPath, {encoding:'utf-8'}, callBackFunction);
}
```

Comment: Ok, i understand, but i cant push the entire code into rules.js? I want minimalist server.js to keep the code easier.

Thank you